# Version C and Fortran90 : optimization for filling subarrays before MPI_Gather

Tags: c, arrays, optimization, fortran, mpi

I have coded a little MPI program that computes with an iterative scheme on a 2D domain : I apply a filter for each cell values (5 points stencil).

In my code, I split global domain into multiple subdomains depending of number of processes. I take `xcell` and `ycell` the size of each subdomain.

Once computation reaches the convergence wanted, I store values for each subdomains into **1D array** (**see below** `xtemp` array) and after, I use `MPI_Gather` to collect all these subdomains into 1D final array (`xfinal` array). In the assignement below (into loop) `x0 array` **represents the 2D subdomain** that I want to copy into `xtemp` `1D array`.

Now, I want to know **if I apply good coding rules and optimizations** **(I mean the way to get the best performances from a runtime point of view**) with the filling of "`xtemp`" array in each version (Language C and Fortran90). `me` is the rank of current MPI process and `xs,xe,ys,ye` the coordinates of each subdomain. We also have to notice that we take for arrays `the convention (i,j) = (rows,columns)` in Language C and Fortran90 versions.

I did :

**Language C :**

```
   /* Fill all 1D xtemp array before MPI_Gather all subdomains :
      inner loop on columns index (second index)                                         
      to optimize since C is row major */                                                
   j=1;
   for (i=xs[me];i<=xe[me];i++) {                                                        
      for (k=0;k<ycell;k++)                                                              
         xtemp[(j-1)*ycell+k] = x0[i][ys[me]+k];                                         
      j=j+1;
   }
```

As you can see, I think the inner index must be on columns (`ys[me]+k`) because C language is **row major**.

Fortran90:

```
   ! Fill all 1D xtemp array before MPI_Gather all subdomains :
   ! inner loop on rows index (first index)
   ! to optimize since F90 is column major                                               
   i = 1                                                                                 
   do j=ys(me),ye(me)
     xtemp((i-1)*xcell+1:i*xcell) = x0(xs(me):xe(me),j)                                  
     i = i+1
   end do
```

Here, I think the inner assignment must be on rows (`xs(me):xe(me)`) because F90 language is **column major**.

Do you agree with these 2 versions of `xtemp` array filling, i.e from an optimization point of view (to get a minimal runtime for both versions, F90 and C language)?

### Update 1

Following the different comments I received, I give more information:

**1. Language C version :**

`For the language C version` of filling `xtemp` 1D array : I use contiguous `x0` 2D array (taking convention `[i,j]=[row,column]`) :

```
double **x0;
x0 = malloc(size_total_x*sizeof(*x0));
x0[0] = malloc(size_total_x*size_total_y*sizeof(**x0));
for (i=1;i<size_total_x;i++) {
   x0[i] = x0[0] + i*size_total_y;
}
```

From what you have indicated, the following block is valid to fill correctly the `xtemp` 1D array :

```
j=1;
   for (i=xs[me];i<=xe[me];i++) {                                                        
      for (k=0;k<ycell;k++)                                                              
         xtemp[(j-1)*ycell+k] = x0[i][ys[me]+k];                                         
      j=j+1;
   }
```

It seems that you confirm it, doesn't it ?

**2. Fortran F90 version :**

`For the F90 version` of filling `xtemp` 1D array : I use also contiguous `x0` 2D array (taking convention `[i,j]=[row,column]`) :

```
double precision, allocatable :: x0(:,:)
allocate(x0(0:size_total_x-1,0:size_total_y-1))
```

About this block above, **is it a right way to allocate 2D contiguous array in Fortran90 ?**

Finally, I didn't see a comment on the filling of `xtemp` 1D array with Fortran90 version, i.e :

```
 i = 1                                                                                 
   do j=ys(me),ye(me)
     xtemp((i-1)*xcell+1:i*xcell) = x0(xs(me):xe(me),j)                                  
     i = i+1
   end do
```

Is it better to do (like since the beginning, from a right optimization point of view):

```
  j = 1                                                                                 
       do i=xs(me),xe(me)
         xtemp((j-1)*ycell+1:j*ycell) = x0(i,ys(me):ye(me))                                  
         j = j+1
       end do
```

or not?

I realize that, between these 2 solutions, the output `xtemp` **will be filled differently** (by blocks of `xcell` for the first one and `ycell` for the second one) but I don't mind it : I just want to use the most optimized way.

Comment: This site is mostly for questions that can have a definite answer that can be accepted. Not for many comments. Are you prepared the answer can just be Yes or No?

Comment: Indeed, there is only one answer for each version (C and F90), i.e the best way to fill xtemp array from an optimization point of view for Fortran90 and C language

Comment: If by *the best way ... from an optimization point of view* you mean the *fastest* why haven't you already measured this ?  And if you don't mean the fastest, what do you mean ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I mean the fastest way. I just want to know if the indexes and the assignments used in my loops are valid to respect optimization in C and F90 languages.

Comment: if you are doing MPI+OpenMP, you can use use OpenMP threads in order to pack/unpack the temporary array.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet :  It is not `j`loop invariant since `i` is incremented and `j`depends on `me` MPI rank : `xtemp((i-1)*xcell+1:i*xcell) = x0(xs(me):xe(me),j)`

Comment: Did you try to send/receive the data directly via an ad hoc MPI derived datatype ? Your data is pretty regular (contiguous data with fixed strides) so I suspect MPI can handle it efficiently.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet. In my code, I already use a MPI_Type_vector column type for Language C and MPI_Type_vector row_type for Fortran, but I use them to exchange values between borders values of each sub-domain. My issue only concerns the respect of right rules once the convergence is reached, when I want to collect all values with MPI_Gather .

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet My first implementation to fill `xtemp` in Language C seems to be good for me (but I would like that someone confirms it) because inner loop is on second index of `x0` 2D array, i.e with `xtemp[(j-1)*ycell+k] = x0[i][ys[me]+k];` but I have doubts about Fortran90 version : indeed, the following instruction does 2 things at the same time : `xtemp((i-1)*xcell+1:i*xcell) = x0(xs(me):xe(me),j)` : on first index with vector `xs(me):xe(me)` and on second with `j`

Comment: in Fortran, the "innermost" loop (e.g. the array assignment) operates on consecutive data (e.g. columns) so it is optimal from a memory access point of view. As long as `xcell` equals `xe(me)-xs(me)+1`, it looks correct to me.

Comment: @youpilat13 I was trying to help you with my macros by taking advantage of C's pointers to speed things up. If the main matrix and your temp matrices are allocated with them you'll gain efficiency, and increased readability. I assumed you were manipulating struct pointers because I had a look at the MPI library docs. I didn't mean for my reply to become contentious, and I'm not sure why it did.

Comment: In C, you built a contiguous 2D array, but the compiler is not made aware of it, and hence treats it as a jagged array.

Comment: I didn't kow that, so what the interest to declare a 2D contiguous array as I did ? this would be useless ?

Comment: It is required if you want to send/receive in one shot the full array, or some bits via derived datatype. It likely helps with respect to cache and prefetch. But from a compiler point of view, this is just a jagged array.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet. ok, I am conforted this declaration is not useless, anyway my functions to exchange borders could not work if I didn't declare it as I did. So now, what have I got to do to optimize the access on this jagged array `x0` ? Did you see the 2 solutions suggested for Fortran90 version, into my **UPDATE 1** ? which one do you advise me to apply ?

Comment: Maybe you can have better performence in assembly?

Comment: i go for the first version (aka the `j` loop). in the second version (aka the `i` loop, the `x0` array is accessed by rows when doing an array assignment, which is suboptimal in Fortran. note that if you have a good compiler, it might automagically swap the loops and hence both versions would have the same performance. but once again, let me re-iterate you should try using derived datatype, that could be even faster since you would not have to manually pack/unpack your data.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet. Thanks a lot, could you summarize and put this advice into an answer, I would like to award this bounty to you, since you gave me precious remarks.

Comment: As a comment on your "is it a right way to allocate 2D contiguous array in Fortran90?": all arrays allocated by an `allocate` statement are contiguous.

Comment: @francescalus good to know it ! thanks

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Actually, in your last answer, looping over `i`is optimal with : `do i=xs(me),xe(me)
         xtemp((j-1)*ycell+1:j*ycell) = x0(i,ys(me):ye(me))` since `x0(i,j)=x0(rows,columns)`and Fortran is **column major**, data are contiguous along rows index (first here `i`), i.e on **one column**, don't you think ?

Comment: The difficulty here for me is that I do 2 things "at the same time" with `xtemp((j-1)*ycell+1:j*ycell) = x0(i,ys(me):ye(me))`: assigning the horizontal vector of values indexed by `ys(me):ye(me)` values and doing it for each `line (row) = i`.

Comment: If you rewrite the Fortran array assignment with a good old `do` loop, then the `i` (aka column) loop will become the outermost loop, which is suboptimal. Makes sense ?

Comment: ok, that view does the trick, what matters is the innermost loop, which does assignement of the column vector with `do j=ys(me),ye(me)
     xtemp((i-1)*xcell+1:i*xcell) = x0(xs(me):xe(me),j)    `, respecting this way the column major rule of Fortran. regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a summary of the various comments on this question

In `Fortran`, or if your array is a `C` contiguous array, an other option is to use derived datatype so there is no need to "pack/unpack" the data to/from a temporary buffer. Since the data is very regular (e.g. a subset of a 2D array), MPI libraries should handle this quite efficiently.

In `Fortran`,

```
i = 1                                                                                 
do j=ys(me),ye(me)
  xtemp((i-1)*xcell+1:i*xcell) = x0(xs(me):xe(me),j)                                  
  i = i+1
end do
```

is likely the most effective way to pack the `x0` array into the `xtemp` temporary buffer. The array assignment syntax can be seen as an implicit loop that iterates on the first index (e.g. column in Fortran) which is optimal.

On the other hand, in `C`,

```
j=1;
for (i=xs[me];i<=xe[me];i++) {                                                        
  for (k=0;k<ycell;k++)                                                              
    xtemp[(j-1)*ycell+k] = x0[i][ys[me]+k];                                         
  j=j+1;
}
```

is likely optimal since the (explicit) innermost loop iterates on the second index (e.g. row) which is optimal in `C`.
Note the `x0` array is declared as a jagged array, and thought is is manually built as a contiguous array, the compiler is not aware of it.
Declaring `x0` as a 2D array (e.g. `double x0[xcell][ycell];`) should lead to better performances.

If your application is hybrid MPI+OpenMP, then you can get an extra boost by using OpenMP when packing/unpacking `x0` to/from `xtemp`. In that case, it might be faster than using derived datatype since dealing with derived datatypes is a serial operation in most MPI implementations.

Answer (score -1):

Awhile ago I wrote some preprocessor code to arbitrarily allocate pointer based 2D and 3D arrays of things. I did this to avoid the implicit multiplication required to access members. Note that you can access the array members linearly as well as dimensionally with this method. I hope it helps:

```
// allocate a 2D array: 'var' is the variable it will be assigned to, 'type' is like float, double, char *, etc
// your var should be declared as type **
// array contents are calloc()ed
// you can linearly address members by &a[0][0];
#define new2DArray(var,type,xDim,yDim) \
do { \
      type *arrayPtr; \
      type **x;      \
      int i; \
      type *p; \
\
      arrayPtr=(type *)calloc(xDim*yDim,sizeof(type)); \
\
      if(arrayPtr==NULL) \
      {  \
         var=NULL; \
         break; \
      }  \
\
      x=(type **)malloc(xDim*sizeof(type **)); \
\
      if(x==NULL)  \
      {  \
        free(arrayPtr);  \
         var=NULL; \
         break;  \
      }  \
\
      for(i=0,p=arrayPtr;i<xDim;i++,p+=yDim) \
         x[i]=p;  \
\
      var=x; \
} while(0)


#define free2DArray(array) do \
{  \
  if(array!=NULL) \
  {  \
    if(array[0]!=NULL) \
      free(array[0]);  \
   free(array);  \
  }  \
} while(0)


#define free3DArray(array) do\
{ \
   if(array!=NULL) \
   {  \
      if(array[0]!=NULL)  \
         free2DArray(array[0]); \
      free(array); \
   } \
} while(0)

// allocate a 3d array: 'var' is the variable it will be assigned to, 'type' is a valid C variable type
// your var should be declared as type ***
// array contents are calloc()ed
// you can linearly address members by &a[0][0][0];
#define new3DArray(var,type,xDim,yDim,zDim) do\
{ \
   type *arrayPtr; \
   type ***xy;  \
   int x,y;  \
   type *p;  \
\
   arrayPtr=(type *)calloc(xDim*yDim*zDim,sizeof(type)); \
   if(arrayPtr==NULL) \
      break; \
   new2DArray(xy,type *,xDim,yDim);  \
   if(xy==NULL)  \
   {  \
      free(arrayPtr);  \
      var=NULL; \
      break; \
   }  \
   p=arrayPtr;  \
   for(x=0;x<xDim;x++) \
      for(y=0;y<yDim;y++,p+=zDim) \
         xy[x][y]=p; \
\
   var=xy; \
} while(0)
```

Comment: So what is the answer to the OP question? Are his(her) optimizations good or optimal? How do your macros help with this? Id the Fortran version good or not?

Comment: His inner loops contain multiplications to access array members. This is much slower than using pointers to access the members.  Using my macros he can access array members as both 1D and 2D which should speed his code up.

Comment: So you think that when you do `a[i][j]` there is no multiplication performed?

Comment: the OP did not detail how `x0` is declared in `C`. If it is a `type **`, then it is less efficient than a `type[][]`, and the macro can help here.

Comment: Vladimir, why would there be? a[i] points to the row a[i][j]  is the pointer a[i]+j

Comment: Oh, you wanted a jagged array? That is really not applicable here, we need a contiguous 2D array.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I see, x0 can be actually jagged. It would surprise me though, but it is possible. It is hard to argue about optimizations then when we don't know such an important thing.

Comment: well, a contiguous 2D array is required if a derived datatype is to be used. otherwise a jagged array is correct, but not as fast as a contiguous array.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thanks Gilles for your comments : could you take a look at my **UPDATE 1** where I put more informations about contiguous `x0`2D array used in both versions ? regards